# javascript error in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

IE 8, 7, and 6 are all complaining about the same character in the below snippet:

```
else if (page == "/about") {

    $.address.title("About");

    $('#main').load("about.php", function () { 
    });  <=  This character (the semi colon)
}
```

You'll see three javascript errros with IE 8 all pointing to the same character.
Am I missing something or is this an invalid character in older version of IE?

Comment: Have you tried actually putting something inside of the function?

Comment: No, something else must be going on.

Comment: There has to be an issue with some other code. auto-added semi-colons or missing braces or semi-colon maybe? you would need to provide an example or more code for us to help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that about.php is returning valid html?

Comment: Can you post more code... and maybe the error you're receiving? Can you replicate it on jsfiddle or point us to a working copy?

Comment: is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Let me push this to a temporary folder on my production site so you can see the error.

Comment: It works in all browsers except older version of IE (version 8 and below)

Comment: Please follow the link and use the test credentials supplied to see the error.

Comment: It's almost a guarantee that you have a stray comma somewhere. 

That is: `{'a':3, 'b':2,}` will break in IE. If you have a decent IDE, this will get marked and picked up as an error. Intelli-J does this, at least.

Comment: Never trust the position that IE tells you.  It may be a problem earlier in the script (missing `}` or something).

Comment: I use netbeans for my PHP development but it hasn't flagged anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who has a similar issue, here was the problem. As mentioned below the error returned from IE was not even close to the correct location. That aside here is what happened. I had a php variable mixed with javascript like so:

```
<textarea class="question_text" id="1" name="1" onFocus="if (this.value == <?php echo($question[0]['question_text']); ?>) { this.value = ''; }"><?php echo($question[0]['question_text']); ?></textarea>
```

I needed to add quotes around the php value retured like so:

```
<textarea class="question_text" id="1" name="1" onFocus="if (this.value == <?php echo("$question[0]['question_text']"); ?>) { this.value = ''; }"><?php echo("$question[0]['question_text']"); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my debugger, your 1st of 3 syntax errors is here: `$.address.title("Edit Profile");`

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me...what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure, but it's throwing errors at all the similar syntaxes: `$.address.title("whatever");`  Is your dollar sign colliding with any other libraries? Modernizer perhaps? Is the address plugin know to work in IE8 in this configuration?